# Grafana 6.2 and custom metrics in Azure App Insights

Tags: azure-application-insights, grafana

I have custom metrics in Azure Application Insights stored as JSON objects.
And I have Grafana version 6.1 som can read and visualize them.

I have upgraded to Grafana v 6.2 and these metrics does show data in it. Why?
Is there a way to troubleshoot Grafana? Any logs about data sources?

Comment: Please check out the grafana troubleshooting guide https://grafana.com/docs/installation/troubleshooting/ or raise an issue with https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues

Comment: The only solution I found is just restructure my Application Insights data.

Comment: The only solution I found is just restructure my Application Insights data. 1. From app Insights Grafa can easy retrieve customEvents Measurements, ie number values. While customDimensions are slow to retrieve. 2. Looks like customMetrics can not be retrieved just with filtering, only with queries. 3 Queries are very slow. Conclusion: Store your data in customEvents Measurements.

Answer (score 0):

To make answer visible to others, I'm summarizing the answer Mikael shared in comment:

Restructure my Application Insights data.

1. From app Insights Grafa can easy retrieve customEvents Measurements, ie number values. While customDimensions are slow to retrieve.
2. Looks like customMetrics can not be retrieved just with filtering, only with queries.
3. Queries are very slow. Conclusion: Store your data in customEvents Measurements